# Only let one app have access to api endpoint?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I am gonna have an open source app in which it needs to send some data to an fastapi python api, how can i make it so that only the app can make requests to the api and not some random person abusing the api endpoint?

Comment: Add authentication (and rate limiting)

Comment: what do you mean by authentication? if you mean like password, then it doesn't make sense because there needs to be a standard password for the apps as anybody should be able to compile the code form the git repo, hence putting the password in the code defeats the purpose of it

Comment: Having an application open source and limiting access to a required service are opposing concepts.

Comment: what do you mean `compile the code form the git repo` ? You don't need password `API KEY` to compile it. You need password `API KEY` only to access API. ANd you should keep `API KEY` in Git repo but user should have to create account on server to get `API KEY`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do that. Even some of the techniques doesn't bother the API endpoint.

1. **IP Restriction:** You can restrict an IP from cloud provider which IP can call the API. Even you can have multiple IPs.
2. **API KEY:** You can provide an API KEY to the API client. When the request come along with the provided key then you work on it otherwise ignore.

**The IP method is much better than doing on the application end.**

Comment: it's not like the app is going to be only restricted to some people, the app can be used anyone either by compiling the code or using our pre packaged app and I can't be whitelisting everyone who uses the app which is not even possible

Comment: So, you app has many APIs and only one API will be restricted. Is it??